# Laravel Sanctum return 401 status for every middleware requests

Tags: laravel, postman, laravel-sanctum

I have problem with my Sanctum API project, every requests to routes in auth middleware return 401 status. Login works good, return new token. I think the problem is that I'm using IP, not domain.

My .env file:

```
APP_URL=192.168.0.26/api
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=192.168.0.26/api
SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
SESSION_DOMAIN=.192.168.0.26/api
```

I'm trying without "api" in domain but still not working.

Comment: `SESSION_DOMAIN=.192.168.0.26/api` looks like an invalid value. The leading dot means all subdomains which is not something that applies to an IP

Answer (score 0):

do you have laravel/passport installed too ?

we have both and it can cause issue, depending in their order in the auth.php config, sanctum guard needs to be before passport guard

If in wrong order, login works but if you try to use the token it will not work, because passport will reject the sanctum token.

Comment: I dont't have passport installed

Comment: i don't think you should add the /api, it's just the domain name, even if your routes are prefixed with a /api, and same for the APP_URL, i think your routes are 192.168.0.26/api/api right now

Comment: do you see your routes when doing route:list command ?

Comment: Yes, but I noticed a strange thing. My route is 
`Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->get('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);`
but route:list show `|        | GET|HEAD | api/logout          |      | App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@logout                 | api                                      |
` I don't know why but route is in bad middleware

Comment: check your route provider, perhaps you have the api middleware defined here